# What is the best way to import r packages into jupyter notebook (using rpy2)?

Tags: r, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am attempting to import an r package (titled "afex") into jupyter notebook using rpy2, for easy work with python. However, I am getting "Selection:" statements followed by blank lines. I tried entering various mirror links into the blank lines, however, nothing helps. I would love to hear if anyone might have encountered this and might be able to help.

See below for code:

```
#Importing key libraries.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

# Download rpy2 package
# Note: The r-modules require Rpy2 to be installed, which should first be done using 
# "conda install -c conda-forge rpy2"
# using Jupyter lab within the conda navigator (terminal within there).
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%load_ext rmagic

# Import the necessary objects from rpy2 and acrivate conversion for dataframe columns
from rpy2.robjects import *
pandas2ri.activate()

# Import the r library for anovas
#import afex
%R install.packages("afex")
```

Here is the problem (output that I get after the above command):
Selection:

The link to a screenshot of the issue is attached as well.[Screenshot of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRgeF.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default R will interactively ask the user to select a mirror from where the package should be downloaded, and for some reason the list of mirrors is not displayed on your system (using Windows ? rpy2 is not supported then).

See the doc to select a mirror and install from Python:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#installing-removing-r-packages

Comment: Thank you so much!!